# How to calculate sine and cosine in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, math

How can I calculate sine and cosine? Is there any library?

Comment: would this help? https://github.com/Sikorkaio/sikorka/blob/master/contracts/trigonometry.sol

Comment: Nice find, @Foxxey

Comment: I created npm package based on the code above (slightly modified). 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/trigonometry.sol